# How to use Samsung SCX 3201 with XSane Image Scanner

Tags: scanner, xsane

Ubuntu 17.10  64 Bit

I recently purchased a Multi function printer Samsung SCX 3201 (now HP)
The printer is working properly.
But am unable to run the scanner. If I run XSane it does not detect the scanner.
I downloaded the drivers from the hp web site. the file is ULD, with .sh files inside it.
How do I install/ use the scanner.
Somewhere it was mentioned that Vue scanner can help, but how do I install it.

Comment: is the printer connected via USB or network?

Comment: Connected via USB.

Answer (score 0):

to install the scanner, the package one downloads from HP/Samsung is uld_v1.00.36_00.91.tar.gz so if one opens a terminal (holding 3 keys down, the control and alt and t keys ..) and then copies the commands below; line by line; ).. *so each line is separate* ..)and pastes them into the terminal; and hit the ENTER key after each paste

(this assumes by default the downloaded package is saved to the Downloads folder)

```
cd Downloads

tar -zxvf uld_v1.00.36_00.91.tar.gz

cd uld

sudo ./install-scanner.sh
```

and that last command should get the scanner set up for you

Comment: Was able to install using the above commands. When I started XSane, it detected the scanner, but after some time gave error: I/O error.

Comment: If I attach the scanner to a Windows PC, the scanner works. Even with Simple Scan, scanning is not possible. Under preferences, it shows the scanner, but does not scan

Comment: I am using Ubuntu on XORG

Comment: so the SANE team reckon it should be supported; http://www.sane-project.org/lists/sane-mfgs-cvs.html#Z-SAMSUNG so perhaps you sign on to their mailing list; tell them your issues; they can offer help http://lists.alioth.debian.org/mailman/listinfo/sane-devel so please talk to them directly; let us know how it goes please